# How to verify if external process terminated abnormally?

Tags: java, exception, processbuilder

Following code snippet runs external process:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111\\bin\\java.exe", 
                "-cp",
                "D:\\nsd-rest\\target\\classes",
                "com.dataart.ExternalProcess"); //java -cp D:\nsd-rest\target\classes my.package.ExternalProcess
Process process = pb.start();
System.out.println(process.waitFor(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)); // prints true
```

The external process looks like this:

```
public class ExternalProcess {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
       throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

The first snippet prints true despite exception throwns from external process.

Is there way to verify that if process finished abnormally ?

Comment: If you read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-), it states that ``waitFor`` returns "false if the waiting time elapsed before the subprocess has exited". That has nothing to do with problems during execution.
Further: The problem is that the definition of "finishing abnormally" is totally up to that process. Exceptions might make it look like an error, yet the process itself (the jvm used here) executed the bytecode correctly. Thus, it terminated normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Process#waitFor(long timeout,
                       TimeUnit unit) Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)

> Returns:
>       true if the subprocess has exited and false if the waiting time elapsed before the subprocess has exited.

You can use the [Process#exitValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue--) to retrieve the exit value, and check if it's `!= 0`

> Returns:
>       the exit value of the subprocess represented by this Process object. By convention, the value 0 indicates normal termination.